# Facebook API php: check if username is set or not

Tags: php, facebook

In which way could I check if FaceBook profile username is set or not? Because I've created a FaceBook profile for do some tests, but it seems that no username is found from profile.

this is my code:

```
$token = $_POST['token'];
$fb_username;
   //get username by GraphApi
  $facebook->setAccessToken($token);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

  try {

  $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me', 'GET');
 
  $fb_username = $user_profile['username'];
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  sendError("Internal error", 0);
  exit(1);
  }
```

Comment: TL;DR `$exists = !empty($user_profile['username'])` - shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably you never gave your test profile a username. you can give a username to your facebook profile by following these steps:

```
1. Click  at the top right of any Facebook page and choose Settings
2. Click General in the left column
3. Look for the setting Username and click Edit to the far right
4. Type your new username in the open field and click Save Changes
```

you could test if a username is there with

```
$usernameExists = isset($user_profile['username']) && $user_profile['username'];
```

Comment: ok, i know how to set username from facebook :D
In my code i need to check if user that call my script has set his username or not !

Comment: right. did it solve your problem? if you can get other fields but not username, this probably solves it.

Comment: If i use my Facebook profile for call script, everithing is fine (because i have an username setted).
But i can't know in advice if all people will call my script has set a username for facebook. I need to know how to check if username is setted or not

Comment: you could test if a username is there with `$usernameExists = isset($user_profile['username']) && $user_profile['username'];`

Comment: maybe if you add the rest of the code where you use that username, i could give you more specific advice.